# am getting something like this,"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Tags: mysql

I am getting the  details of product from the database. Here is my sample code I am unable to display images of the products! Can anyone help me out please?

**The code to insert the product details in the database:**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<?php
include("includes/db.php");
?>
<html>
<head>
<title> Inserting product</title>

<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });
  </script>

</head>
<body bgcolor="skyblue">
<form action="insert_product.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <table align="center" width="700" border="2" bgcolor="orange">
     <tr align="center">
          <td colspan="7"><h2>Insert New Post Here.</h2></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
          <td align="right"><b>Product Title:</b></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="product_title" size="50" required /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
          <td align="right"><b>Product Category:</b></td>
          <td>
          <select name="product_cat" required>
          <option>Select a categogory</option>
            <?php 
            $get_cats = "select * from categories";
    $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);

    while($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){

        $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];
        $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];
        echo "<option value='$cat_id'>$cat_title</option>";
    }
            ?>
          </select>
          </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
          <td align="right"><b>Product Brand:</b></td>
          <td>
          <select name="product_brand" required>
          <option>Select a Brand</option>
            <?php 
            $get_brands = "select * from brands";
    $run_brands = mysqli_query($con, $get_brands);

    while($row_brands=mysqli_fetch_array($run_brands)){

        $brand_id = $row_brands['brand_id'];
        $brand_title = $row_brands['brand_title'];
        echo "<option value='$brand_id'>$brand_title</option>";
    }
            ?>
          </select>
          </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
          <td align="right"><b>Product Image:</b></td>
          <td><input type="file" name="product_image" required/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
          <td align="right"><b>Product Price:</b></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="product_price" size="50" required/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
          <td align="right"><b>Product Description:</b></td>
          <td><textarea name="product_desc" cols="20" rows="10"></textarea></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
          <td align="right"><b>Product Keywords</b></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="product_keywords" size="50" required/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr align="center">
          <td colspan="7"><b><input type="submit" name="insert_post" value="Insert Product Now"/></b></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['insert_post'])){
       //getting the text data from the fields.
     $product_title = $_POST ['product_title']; 
     $product_cat = $_POST ['product_cat']; 
     $product_brand = $_POST ['product_brand']; 
     $product_price = $_POST ['product_price']; 
     $product_desc = $_POST ['product_desc']; 
     $product_keywords = $_POST ['product_keywords']; 
      //getting the image data from the fields.
      $product_image = $_FILES['product_image'][name];
      $product_image_tmp = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'];

      move_uploaded_file($product_image_tmp,"product_images/$product_image");

      $insert_product = "insert into products (product_cat,product_brand,product_title,product_price,product_desc,product_image,product_keywords) values ('$product_cat','$product_brand','$product_title','$product_price','$product_desc',' $product_image','$product_keywords')";
   $insert_pro = mysqli_query($con,$insert_product);
   if($insert_pro) {
       echo "<script>alert('Product has been inserted!')</script>";
       echo "<script>window.open('insert_product.php','_self')</script>";
   }
   }
?>
```

**The function part.**

```
    <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ecommerce");
//getting the categories
function getcats(){
    global $con;
    $get_cats = "select * from categories";
    $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);

    while($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){

        $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];
        $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];
        echo "<li><a href='#'>$cat_title</a></li>";
    }

    }

//getting the Brands
function getBrands(){
    global $con;
    $get_brands = "select * from brands";
    $run_brands = mysqli_query($con, $get_brands);

    while($row_brands=mysqli_fetch_array($run_brands)){

        $brand_id = $row_brands['brand_id'];
        $brand_title = $row_brands['brand_title'];
        echo "<li><a href='#'>$brand_title</a></li>";
    }

    }

    function getpro() {
        global $con;

        $get_pro = "select * from products order by RAND() LIMIT 1,6";
        $run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $get_pro);
        while($row_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro)){
            $pro_id = $row_pro['product_id'];
            $pro_cat = $row_pro['product_cat'];
            $pro_brand = $row_pro['product_brand'];
            $pro_title = $row_pro['product_title'];
            $pro_price = $row_pro['product_price'];
            $pro_image = $row_pro['product_image'];
            echo "
            <div id='single_product'>
            <h3>$pro_title</h3>
            <img src='\\ecommerce\admin_area\product_images\$pro_image' width='180' height='180' /> 
            <p><b> $pro_price </b></p>
            </div>
            ";
        }
        }                               
?>




**The web page to display all details**
    <!DOCTYPE>
<?php
include("functions/functions.php");
?>
<html>
     <head>
        <title>Gal Baking Services LTD online Shop.</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="admin_area/product_images/style.css" media="all" /> 
     </head>
<body>
    <div class="main_Wrapper">

        <div class="header_wrapper"> 
        <img id="logo" src="images/ad bunner.jpg" />
        <img id="bunner" src="images/ad bunner.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="menubar">
            <ul id="menu">
                 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">All products</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">My account</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Shopping cart</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="form">
                 <form method="get" action="result.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="text" name="user_query" placeholder="Search a product" />
                    <input type="submit" name="search" value="search" />
                 </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content_wrapper">
        <div id="sidebar"> 

           <div id="sidebar_title">Categories</div>
           <ul id="carts">
           <?php getcats();?>
            </ul>
         <div id="sidebar_title">Brands</div>

           <ul id="carts">
           <?php getBrands();?>
           </ul>

        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content_area">
           <div id="products_box">

           <?php getpro(); ?>

           </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"> 
           <h2 style="text-align:center; padding-top:30px;">&copy;2016 by www.krumblefresh.com </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would wish to thank everyone for your participation and for your support .
After straggling with my code on how to display images from mysql database,i came to realize that my code was perfect only that i had made some silly mistakes on the following lines of the insert_product.php file,
"$product_image = $_FILES['product_image']**[name];**".I failed to enclose the 'name' inside the single quotes ''.It should be,
$product_image = $_FILES['product_image']['name'];.
Also,on the following line
*

> $insert_product = "insert into products
>   (product_cat,product_brand,product_title,product_price,product_desc,product_image,product_keywords)
>   values
>   ('$product_cat','$product_brand', '$product_title','$product_price','$product_desc',
>   **' $product_image'**,'$product_keywords')";
>
> *, i had included a blank space inside the single quotes near *$product_image*.Its supposed to be ,
>
> $insert_product = "insert into products
>   (product_cat,product_brand,product_title,product_price,product_desc,product_image,product_keywords)
>   values
>   ('$product_cat','$product_brand','$product_title','$product_price','$product_desc','$product_image','$product_keywords')";
>   Thank you all.